# Disable prefix search of input field

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on autocompletion for an HTML input field.
Therefore I get suggestions from an API using Ajax. **All** results returned by the API are applicable given the input. In the last step, I fill a datalist with the suggestions. The datalist is connected to the input field

```html
<input list="suggestions">
<datalist id="suggestions">
    <option value="CN Tower">
    <option value="Tower of London">
</datalist>
```

The problem is that there may be results that do not have the given input as prefix, but are correct as well.
For instance, if the user types "Tower", suggestions should be "Tower of London" which has "Tower" as prefix, but also "CN Tower" which does not start with the Input value. But the latter gets filtered out by the input field.

Is there a way to disable this internal prefix search of the input field?

Comment: Can you please add javascript codes too?

Comment: "But the latter gets filtered out by the input field." How do you mean this? In the code snippet you've provided, both terms appear if I start to type "tower"!?

Comment: @RakeshSojitra I don't think that this would add value to the question. It's just an Ajax request with adding the result in form of `<option>` tags to the datalist. But the problem can be seen with the HTML code, too: If you type "Tower", only one result is shown.

Comment: I see both when I type "Tower", which browser and version are you using...I tested in Firefox and chrome.

Comment: @feeela web-nomad Oh, I see. It works at least in Firefox, but not in Edge and IE. But this does only solve my problem in this case. Another case could be that the searched term is found in the "Description" field of an entity, but only the "Name" is returned. So the name does not contain the searched term. I guess that in this case this entity is not shown as suggestion of the input field.

Comment: @Flogex There is no such thing as a “description” in a datalist. What do you mean? See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: @Flogex: first I am sure you are not using pure javascript and using any ready-made library and you didn't mentioned proper tags with library too. so you need to clarify all this things with proper codes

Comment: Also if you are using AJAX call then its server side filtered data so how can you filter data at server side too

Comment: @feeela Sorry for being incomprehensible. So imagine, in the backend I have a class containing "Name" and "Description" fields. The API searches both fields for the given input, but in the input field on the website only the name gets displayed. Now the API would return an entity `{name: "Space Needle", description: "A Tower"}`, but in the datalist, the option would be `<option value="Space Needle">`. I want to show this as suggestion, too, although the name does not contain the term "Tower".

Comment: @Flogex `datalist` is completely un-supported (buggy support) on IE and Edge. See this - https://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist It is 100% supported only on Chrome, even firefox has partial support for this element.